# Regular expression, everything until a pattern

Tags: regex, expression

I am looking to write a regular expression that groups on a specific pattern. For example for the string:

```
"File=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ QQQQQQQQQQ.txt size=ten check=true test=true"
```

I would like groups of:

```
File=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ QQQQQQQQQQ.txt
size=ten
check=true
test=true
```

Normally I could just look for spaces but if my file name has a space in it then this doesn't work. So I need to match everything until I hit any character plus an =.

Answer (score 2):

You could split by `[ ](?=\w+=)`.  The stuff in parentheses is a "lookahead assertion", and will match a space only if whatever's following it looks like a parameter.

If you're intent on matching rather than splitting, `(?:[^ ]| (?!\w+=))+` should work.  The `(?!...)` part is a *negative* lookahead assertion, so the space will only match if whatever follows *doesn't* look like a param.

Note, not all regex engines support lookahead assertions.  Most do, particularly PCRE-flavored ones...but check your regex engine's docs for the proper syntax.

(Also: i'm using `[ ]` because Markdown hates leading spaces in inline code.  You could just use a space there instead (without the brackets), or `\s` if you want to allow any whitespace char to separate params.)

Comment: Hi cHao, I probably should of mentioned that I was using Java, I've just tried this using the following website and it doesn't work http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

any ideas?

Comment: Yeah.  This pattern isn't made to match; it's made to split.  Use it like `String[] pieces = yourString.split(" (?=\w+=)");`.  If you match, it'll only match the spaces, which is a bit less than useful.  Just edited to include an expression that should be usable for matching.